# OpenGL VBO error causing system exit

Tags: exception, opengl, crash, vbo

I'm using JOGL with to load an OBJ model and display it in a GL canvas using a VBO. Everything is work for the most part however, there are some models where the vertices must be deformed. For example, I have an arrow object and must be able to deform the stem of the arrow to make the tail as long/short as needed while maintaining the object geometry for the arrow head.
This works fine for one instance of the renderer but when I try and add another one to the scene, the system exits on the GLDrawElements call and outputs this error log. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm at a complete loss.

```
    #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000069e3e4c8, pid=6544, tid=2692
#
# JRE version: 6.0_21-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0-b16 mixed mode windows-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [nvoglnt.dll+0x93e4c8]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

...
Stack: [0x0000000052640000,0x0000000052740000],  sp=0x000000005273ecb0,  free space=3fb0000000000000000k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [nvoglnt.dll+0x93e4c8]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLImpl.glDrawElements0(IIIJ)V
J  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLImpl.glDrawElements(IIIJ)V
j  com.sonogenics.model.AbstractModelHandler$Renderer.display(Ljavax/media/opengl/GL;)V+196
j  com.sonogenics.model.AbstractModelHandler$Renderer.display(Ljavax/media/opengl/GL;Lcom/sonogenics/camera/SimpleProjection;FFFLcom/sonogenics/playout/Field;)V+436
...
```

Comment: We need more code, debug output and info. The crash log just says that you did something illegal, which crashed the GL driver (likely a mixup of handles/buffer pointers, etc... exactly what is difficult to say without more info). You could try to run your app in an OpenGL debugger and see if it catches anything.

Comment: @Chris, @Macke: What we have here is a process crash, not a system crash.  A driver crash actually would bring down the whole system.

Comment: @Ben: We have a user-side driver crash, since the access violation occured in nvoglnt.dll (NVidia's WindowsNT OpenGL driver). Depends on your definition of driver though.

Comment: @Macke, @Ben, Cheers for the help guys. I've updated the original post with the rendering code. Thanks again!

Comment: @Chris: New problem, new question, plz.

Comment: As requested, here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137794/java-heap-memory-with-opengl-model-renderer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GDebugger](http://www.gremedy.com/) to see what call causes the error and check for invalid data in your gl calls.

It's quite awesome. :)

Answer (score 1):

ACCESS_VIOLATION means you told GL to read memory that is outside the the 'good' areas :)

Within Drawelements there are a couple reasons that could be, you want to check where you setup the GL buffers as well as what you are passing into DrawElements.

- -One of your buffers was a bad address, causing it to read from who
  knows where
- -One of your offsets, strides, were too long causing GL to go beyond the
  end of an allocation
- -You number of verts you said were in the model was too long... causing it
  to go beyond the end of the
  allocation
- -Your VBO allocation wasn't large enough for the stride * number of
  verts